# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote this code to find which one of dtExistCosts doesn,y exit in costsList.

```
var costMustbeDeleteDt = (
        from e in dtExistCosts.AsEnumerable()
        where !(from c in costsList 
                select Convert.ToString(c.CostRecordId))
                            .Contains(e.Field<string>("DETAIL_HAZ_PK"))
        select e).CopyToDataTable();
```

but when I run it I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type `System.Decimal` to type `System.String`

in

```
!(from c in costsList 
  select Convert.ToString(c.CostRecordId))
        .Contains(e.Field<string>("DETAIL_HAZ_PK"))
```

why?

Comment: What type is `DETAIL_HAZ_PK`?

Comment: It's the name of column that i want to check.

Comment: Great, and what *type* is it?

Answer (score 3):

```
.Contains(e.Field<string>("DETAIL_HAZ_PK"))
```

The exception should be at this line, you cannot do explicit conversion for a decimal to string as the exception suggested.

You may do:

```
.Contains(Convert.ToString(e.Field<decimal>("DETAIL_HAZ_PK")))
```

Of course, compare values directly by decimal should be the case but this answer your question on why.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert two numerical values (c.CostRecordId and the value of "DETAIL_HAZ_PK") to string before comparing them which is not only unnecessary but also leads to the error you described.

Try this instead:

```
var costMustbeDeleteDt = (from e in dtExistCosts.AsEnumerable()
  where !(from c in costsList select c.CostRecordId)
      .Contains(e.Field<decimal>("DETAIL_HAZ_PK"))
  select e).CopyToDataTable();
```

Additionally, I would suggest to improve the readability of your selection by introducing a variable for the costList IDs and converting your LINQ queries to the method chain syntax:

```
var costsListIds = costsList.Select (c => c.CostRecordId);

var costMustbeDeleteDt = dtExistCosts
    .Where (existCost => !costsListIds.Contains (existCost.Field<decimal>("DETAIL_HAZ_PK"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it and I convert the c.CostRecordId to decimal too, and it worked.